# jquery tablesorter problem

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter

hello
i get some help here yesterday for a problem i was having tablesorter. if i run the backend query on its own it displays the results ok. but i call it from another page from dropdown it displays all records and no errors are being seen in firebug. where am i going wrong? thanks

this code works on its own.

getuserlog.php

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("sample", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM logger_log WHERE idusr_log = '".$q."' order by datein_log desc";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table id=\"userlog\" class=\"tablesorter\" cellspacing=\"1\">
<thead>
<tr>
<th align=\"left\">Ip Address</th>
<th align=\"left\">Date In</th>
<th align=\"left\">Date Out</th>
</tr>
</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ip_log'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($row['datein_log'])) . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($row['dateout_log'])) . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

  }
   echo"</tbody>";
echo "</table>";


mysql_close($con);
?>
<div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
        <img src="css/blue/first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="css/blue/prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <img src="css/blue/next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="css/blue/last.png" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option  value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<link href="css/blue/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script>
        $(function() {
        $("#userlog")
            .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
            .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
    });

        </script>
```

and this is the page i am calling it from.

userlog.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuserlog.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="userlogTxt">This report shows all users who have logged in up until: <?php echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s"); ?></div>
        <br />
        <?php
            $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());

            mysql_select_db("sample") or die(mysql_error());

            $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user_usr ORDER BY name_usr ASC', $conn);
            echo '<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">';
            echo '<option value="selected">'. 'Select a user' . '</option>';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
            {

            echo '<option value="'.$row['id_usr'].'">'.$row['name_usr'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        ?>
    <br /><br />
<div id="txtHint" class="userlogTxt">Logging information will be shown here.</div></div>
```

@inti

it is not pulling any date from the db. just displaying header and pager.

userlog.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script> 
<link href="css/blue/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function showUser(str)     
        {  
            $.get("getuserlog.php?q="+str,function(response) {
                $("#txtHint").html(response);
            // Tablesorter will run, just after you loaded the ajax response             
            $("#userlog").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
            .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")
            });         
                });     
        }
</script> 

<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="userlogTxt">This report shows all users who have logged in up until: <?php echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s"); ?></div>
        <br />
        <?php
            $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());

            mysql_select_db("sample") or die(mysql_error());

            $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user_usr ORDER BY name_usr ASC', $conn);
            echo '<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">';
            echo '<option value="selected">'. 'Select a user' . '</option>';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
            {

            echo '<option value="'.$row['id_usr'].'">'.$row['name_usr'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        ?>
    <br /><br />
<div id="txtHint" class="userlogTxt">Logging information will be shown here.</div></div>
```

getuserlog.php

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("sample", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM logger_log WHERE idusr_log = '".$q."' order by datein_log desc";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table id=\"userlog\" class=\"tablesorter\" cellspacing=\"1\">
<thead>
<tr>
<th align=\"left\">Ip Address</th>
<th align=\"left\">Date In</th>
<th align=\"left\">Date Out</th>
</tr>
</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ip_log'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($row['datein_log'])) . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($row['dateout_log'])) . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

  }
   echo"</tbody>";
echo "</table>";


mysql_close($con);
?>
<div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
        <img src="css/blue/first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="css/blue/prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <img src="css/blue/next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="css/blue/last.png" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option  value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

where have i gone wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you, to use the jQuery Ajax functions in `userlog.php`, and since the script inside `getuserlog.php` is constant, move it to the `userlog.php`, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<link href="css/blue/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(str)
    {
        $.get("getuserlog.php?q="+str,function(response) {
            $("#txtHint").html(response);
            // Tablesorter will run, just after you loaded the ajax response
            $("#userlog").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
                         .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
        });
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Put all you javascript in the main page. The ajax response should only contain the data you want to get from the server.

Comment: hi. thanks for reply. are you suggesting having just one file: userlog.php. thanks

Comment: No, you need the `getuserlog.php`, but use javascript only in the main page `userlog.php`.

Comment: please see updated code and tell me where i am going wrong. thanks

Comment: @ploppy well, there may be something wrong with your sql query, try debugging it a bit, echo `$sql` or something

Comment: does the tablesorter script read all the db for results initially or just the records specified in the pager. got it going thanks to your help but it is very slowwwwww... thanks